# Issue Type code for "TASK" in a JIRA ticket

Tags: c#, rest, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to create a JIRA ticket using JIRA SDK.

Want to know the code for issue type "**TASK**"- for a "**BUG**" it is 18.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you are using jira-rest-api. From the [jira developer docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-create-issue), I can see,

```
curl -D- -u fred:fred -X POST --data {see below} -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8090/rest/api/2/issue/
```

with data as,

```
{
    "fields": {
       "project":
       { 
          "key": "TEST"
       },
       "summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.",
       "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
       "issuetype": {
          "name": "Bug" //You should specify it as Task
       }
   }
}
```

In general, you can inspect meta data first like explained in this [page](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-discovering-meta-data-for-creating-issues).